# Gas leak detector goes off but no bubbles

Tags: leak, dryer, gas, natural-gas

Before I start, the valve from the wall is off and the outlet is capped at this point.

I checked a gas connection for my dryer after smelling a faint odor near my laundry closet. Using a Home-Flex detector I got low to mild readings near the wall. I removed the auto shut off valve that came with my dryer hose kit in favor of a straight connection to my gas hose. That valve is the kind of thing that goes over the 1/2" flared fitting from the wall valve and has another 1/2" outlet. In [this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/BrassCraft-Safety-PLUS2-1-2-in-O-D-Gas-Dryer-and-Range-Installation-Kit-w-Thermal-Excess-Flow-Valve-60-500-BTU-PSCTE1106-K5/304227958) photo it is the teal banded fitting.

After tightening up the connections I put Oatey leak detector everywhere and didn't see any bubbles. After a minute of that I pulled out the Home-Flex detector again. While it did take about a minute it did start detecting a low reading again.

What is my best course of action here? I'm thinking if another hose isn't able to seal correctly on the valve the next thing is to replace the 1/2" valve from the wall in case the threads on the flared fitting are damaged.

Comment: The leak may not be at something you intended to change... Or at something you changed at all. I would recommend turning off the main gas valve,  pulling the main breaker, getting out of the house, and calling the gas company or a pro to find and fix it for you. Gas fitting is conceptually straightforward but the consequences of getting it wrong can be severe, so I really don't suggest anyone attempt it without full training ;I won't touch it myself.